# How to pipe an output to printf, when the \n text is not being breaken by bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, printf

I have text like this:

```bash
"while compiling ejs\n\nIf the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:\nhttps://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint%5CnOr, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.","stack":"SyntaxError: (...)"
```

Which is NOT being broken into lines in bash (running a `npm run Script`)

How can I pipe it into printf, or whatever tool, to make \n to be actually rendered as a break-line?

I tried viewing multiple sources on piping text to make bash read the string \n into actually a linebreak, but unsucessefully.

I expect '\n' to actually break lines.

#### **SOLUTION:**

As @Charles Duffy pointed out,

`npm run Script | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%b\n' "$line"; done`

works. The final output looks like these, to give more closure:

```bash
If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (<ommited-path>/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:673:12)
    at Object.compile (<ommited-path>/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:398:16)
```

Comment: You can use bash `echo -e "..."`, or the standard `printf %b "..."`

Comment: (`printf '%b\n' "..."` if one wants to be equivalent to bash's nonstandard `echo -e` as opposed to its similarly nonstandard `echo -en` -- btw, note that bash's behavior around echo is inconsistent based on runtime settings; the `printf` approach is more reliable even if the shell is 100% certain to be bash)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Your question is a bit unclear. You say you want to pipe it to a tool (printf or alike) to render the newline characters. Where does the string come from. Is it output from a program, do you get it from a textfile is it assigned to a variable?

Comment: That said, that text looks like it _might_ be JSON. If it is, `jq -r` is a better tool for converting it to raw text.

Comment: It's a stream of text. I can't use `echo -e`, because it breaks the stream. I don't know how to pass to `printf` though. Just piping ` npm run Script | printf %b` silences the output (nothing appears)

Comment: `printf '%b\n' "$(npm run Script)"`

Comment: Or `npm run Script | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%b\n' "$line"; done`

Comment: Or, if I'm correct and it's JSON, `npm run Script | jq -r .`

Comment: It's an output from a `./bin/ww` express app, which is throwing errors from ejs view. It's a running stream of javascript error. Comes from `npm run <script>`.

Comment: Actually, the comma between the string and the `"stack"` implies that you're leaving something out. Is there perhaps a `{` at the beginning of output, and a `}` after what's shown?

Comment: `npm run` doesn't have a single well-defined output format, so that's not as helpful as one might want (different programs you can run with npm can have different kinds of output)

Comment: Charles, that did it! Thanks a LOT! I was in such a pain.

Comment: `npm run Script | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%b\n' "$line"; done` did it

Comment: Please post the comment, so I can accept the awnser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `while read` loop to collect lines and then put them into `printf %b` for formatting should do what you want:

```
npm run Script | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%b\n' "$line"; done
```

The general pattern used here is documented in [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Some notes:

- The exit status of this pipeline will be that of the `while` loop, *unless* you run `set -o pipefail` first to make a failure anywhere in a pipeline cause the entire command to report a failure.
- Using `IFS=` stops spaces at the front or end of the input from being deleted.
- Using `-r` stops backslashes from being removed by `read` itself before the `line` variable is defined.
- `printf '%b\n'` is the [POSIX-advised alternative](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) to what bash implements in a nonstandard way as `echo -e` (see the *APPLICATION USAGE* section of the link; there are also concrete examples in the answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)).

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the solution and further documentation and explanation of what is going on.